# Cartesian product of an open and a closed set on product topology

Tags: general-topology

Say you have a set $A$ which is closed in $X$ and a set $B$ which is closed in $Y$. Then, of course, $A^{c}\times B^{c}$ would be a base element for the product topology on $X \times Y$, and therefore, an open set in it. But, what can be said of the products $A^{c}\times B$ and $A\times B^{c}$? Where one is closed and the other one open? What about of the union ($A^{c}\times B) \cup (A\times B^{c}$)?

Comment: Look at products of intervals from $\mathbb{R}$ in $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 0):

By simple examples it's clear that $A^c \times B$ and $A \times B^c$ and their union need not be closed nor open.

But $(A \times B)^c = (X\times B^c) \cup (A^c \times Y)$ is open (as a union of two subbasic open subsets) so $A \times B$ is closed in $X \times Y$...